# Properly implement the Simple File System Protocol on a RAM Disk

Tags: uefi, edk2

I have need to make a RAM Disk during the DXE phase of UEFI. Beginning in version 2.6 of the UEFI spec, there is a RAM Disk protocol. I've successfully used this to make a RAM Disk. This RAM Disk must also have a FAT32 system on it.

I am building this FAT32 partition programmatically *before* I install the RAM Disk. From reading the spec, it seems that *firmware* (i.e. black magic), ".. automatically adds an EFI_DISK_IO_PROTOCOL to any EFI_BLOCK_IO_PROTOCOL interface that is produced." (This is discussed [in this paragraph](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/13_Protocols_Media_Access.html#efi-disk-io-protocol).) [Digging through the RAM Disk DXE driver](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/MdeModulePkg/Universal/Disk/RamDiskDxe/RamDiskProtocol.c#L700), it is the case that a BLOCK_IO_PROTOCOL is produced by firmware for any RAM Disk that is instantiated.

So, from the spec, it would seem that *if a recognized file system format is present on a supported block device or disk I/O device*, the firmware should automatically associate the requisite protocols for this. This isn't what is happening. Using QEMU to test my FW Volumes, when the UEFI Shell starts, I have mappings for the block devices but no FS*n* mappings:

```
BLK1: Alias(s):
   VirtualDisk(0x38B74018,0x3BB74017,0)
BLK2: Alias(s):
   VirtualDisk(0x38B74018,0x3BB74017,0)/HD(1,GPT,CF0C3344-CAF3-46C5-A72B-920DFD878FB2,0x800,0x17000)
...
```

I am instantiating my RAM Disk with

```c
EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
RegisterMyRd()
{
    EFI_STATUS stat;
    EFI_RAM_DISK_PROTOCOL *pRdProto;
    EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL *pRdPathProto;

    /* There is a static EFI_PHYSICAL_ADDRESS *pRamDisk for this compilation unit */

    stat = gBS->LocateProtocol(
        &gEfiRamDiskProtocolGuid,
        NULL,
        (VOID**)&pRdProto);
    ASSERT_EFI_ERROR(stat);

    stat = pRdProto->Register(
        (UINT64)pRamDisk,
        (UINT64)RAM_DISK_SIZE,  /* a define for 1024 * 1024 * 48 */
        &gEfiVirtualDiskGuid,
        NULL,
        &pRdPathProto);
    ASSERT_EFI_ERROR(stat);
    return stat;
}
```

So, my RAM Disk is made and the GUID Partition Table is even discovered. There are BLOCK_IO_PROTOCOL(s) instantiated, but for some reason when the Shell is invoked and the mappings are provided, [there aren't any File System objects as expected](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/ShellPkg/Library/UefiShellCommandLib/UefiShellCommandLib.c#L1436). Though a 48MiB RD is kinda small, using that very same sized "disk" to QEMU works just fine, i.e. `qemu-system-x86_64 ... -hda my_disk.img` which results in an `FS0:` mapping for the "disk" on the PCI bus.

Must I add an EFI_SIMPLE_FILE_SYSTEM_PROTOCOL onto the device handle for the RAM Disk? Does that imply implementing my own functions for `OpenVolume()` and then the many for `EFI_FILE_PROTOCOL`?

Comment: Was a DiskIO protocol installed at the ram disk handle (shell commands devices and openinfo)? Have you tried to connect the drivers after creating the ram disk (shell command connect [-r])?

Comment: @MiSimon I believe that, from the spec, the `DiskIoProtocol` is produced for each `BlockIoProtocol` that is produced. From the link I provided, "The firmware automatically adds an EFI_DISK_IO_PROTOCOL interface to any EFI_BLOCK_IO_PROTOCOL interface that is produced." The DXE RAM Disk driver _does make a BLOCK_IO_PROTOCOL_. I will attempt to verify that a DISK_IO proto is also on the handle.

Comment: @MiSimon I have verified that an `EFI_DISK_IO_PROTOCOL` instance _is installed on the handle_ for the RAM Disk. The method used: `gBS->LocateHandleBuffer(ByProtocol, &gEfiDiskIoProtocolGuid, ...)` and then check that the RAM Disk handle was in the returned list of handles. However, that same process shows that, indeed, an `EFI_SIMPLE_FILE_SYSTEM_PROTOCOL` is not on the RAM Disk.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, I'm answering my own question. There hasn't been any traction on this, except the comments.

I did find the solution. My interpretation of the spec is correct. When things are laid out correctly, the firmware *does make file system protocols* for this object automatically. This last statement even alludes to the problem.

Succinctly, I had the FAT32 system misaligned with information about where it would be. Now comes the more in depth answer.

The UEFI (a.k.a. firmware) makes a Block I/O protocol for both the entire drive and for the partition defined in the GPT [see this section for details](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/05_GUID_Partition_Table_Format.html#guid-partition-table-gpt-disk-layout-1). It was the second block that was being misaligned. I was getting the `BLKn` device for both the entire RAM Disk and the GUID Partition Table, but the File System was missing.

After placing the FAT32 structure ([see the spec](https://academy.cba.mit.edu/classes/networking_communications/SD/FAT.pdf)) in the LBA that the GUID Partition Array Entry claimed it would be, the expected file system mapping is present `FS0`.

Because I was using QEMU for development, I did careful scrutiny of the "hard drive" (a file made with `parted` and `mkdosfs -F 32`) passed to the VM with `-hda fs0_disk.img`.

Thank you to @MiSimon for the question about whether `EFI_DISK_IO_PROTOCOL` objects were on the RAM Disk. This question helped to point me in the right direction.